# A good Unity project to get started

Tags: unity

What types of game should I start making to get started with Unity 3D? Any ideas?

Remember: it should be small, and not art-intensive.

Comment: -1, "what game should I make" isn't really a good question.  Also for beginning games there's already a pretty thorough list here. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with

Comment: In any game engine a know gametype would be a good place to start. I have a few suggestions. 1) Pac-Man clone. 2) Space Invaders/Galaxy 3) Frogger 4) any other "basic" game that seems too simple always shows up to have enough for beginners. Try some of them first. Then you will learn a lot. If you dont know the games, use Youtube to learn about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take one of the existing Unity example projects and modify it.  This gives you a good solid base to work from.

Comment: I've always felt like a bit of an alien because this approach never works for me. Am I the only one? I always have to learn new tools by building from scratch; I never get anywhere by looking at example projects.

Comment: I realize this is 5 years later, but i am kinda that way too :)

Comment: I'll allow it ;)