# What are the Starting Games I need to make?[Best steps for a beginner Game Developer?]

Tags: software-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good games to “earn your wings” with?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with)

Hai,
     I'm new to the genre "Creating Games".Previously i had done only porting.I need some suggestion's for making a game.

```
  What are the basic game logics i need to start with?
             - Should i write Tic-Tac-Toe game? - Actually this seem very basic to me.
```

I'm totally confused on where to start with.I like to create big games but after starting i feel the game is too heavy to handle.
Can any one list out the basic needs of a Game Play programmer?
I don't mind using any platform (Flash,c++,objective-c) but i need to know what are the game logic's i need to know before i start a big game.