# What basic windows form games should I build as a newbie in game development?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

I am a complete newbie in game development. I want to know about some basic games that I can start building with simple algorithms and basic knowledge. I have already made few basic games like minesweeper, TicTacToe, basic card games, and a snake game. I just want to have an idea to start a new fun project.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some random ideas:

- A basic Tetris clone. Good practice in working with arrays and event handling, but not too heavy on the graphics side. Getting the blocks to behave exactly as in modern Tetrises (e.g. Tetris DS) is quite a challenge though!
- A point'n'click shooting gallery. You can have fun doing the graphics and sound effects, but the basic algorithms should be quite simple.
- A Geometry Wars type game. Some more geometry is involved, and this would generally be great practice if that is the direction you want to move towards.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Thomas's answer; any 2D based game would be a good idea. Look at a lot of retro games and try and emulate one you really like the look of. Games like Asteroids, Space Invaders and Mario are all challenging enough to, but not too drastically difficult to implement.