# Is it possible to combine Blender with PHP?

Tags: 3d, blender, php

I want to build a web game with Blender and I know PHP.
Is it possible to mesh Blender with PHP?

Comment: You can export rendered images, then use those. But without more details, it'll be hard to answer this question. Not sure if you've thought this far ahead or not, but you need to tell us what you want to do. Do you mean make the graphics for a game?

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got some gaps in your knowledge of programming / gamedev. I would suggest you take a step back and work on some simple games to get a little more experience.

Comment: Wait... What? PHP, as far as I know, is an HTML preprocessing language. How do you plan to do anything graphical with it?

Comment: He never said he wants to do anything graphical with PHP, which of course just leads to another huge problem with this question: what exactly are you trying to do anyway? Talk about vague!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: *not really*.  Blender can be [used directly to implement game logic](http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/features/).  Also internally [Blender can be scripted using Python](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/09/22/introduction-to-scripting-in-the-blender-game-engine-part-01/).

As @Byte56 mentions you could create graphics in Blender and then export them.

But, as @Bane and @stephelton mention, you appear to have some holes in your knowledge of game development, and possibly development generally.

I would recommend you take a look at [How do I make games? A Path to Game Development](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/how-do-i-make-games-a-path-to-game-development-r892) and even some other questions here or on related SE's like:

- [What are good games to “earn your wings” with?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with)
- [What technology should I use for a web-based game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3003/what-technology-should-i-use-for-a-web-based-game)
- [Creating web based games](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118492/creating-web-based-games)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. You can use urllib and open a http connection from the python, get data from PHP and visualize in Blender. You can even do this online using Burster [Burster website](http://geta3d.com).

The second possibility, depending on what you realy want to do. If you want in example to do some modification of camera using the web, and you want to get a rendered image from Blender over the Web you can implement very simple WWW server in Python in Blender (example here: [making a simple web server in python](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php)).

So, if you can describe your task in more details, i would be able to answer with examples of how to do this .

Answer (score 0):

If you know PHP you also know that PHP is a server-side scripting language which in turn needs another language (html, html5 for instance) to display something.

So if we consider your question as: "*Is it possible to combine Blender with html/html5?*", then the answer is **yes you somehow can do it.**.

For example, you can load a model exported from Blender using [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) which is a JavaScript API for rendering interactive 3D graphics within any compatible web browser without the use of plug-ins. It is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 and provides an API for 3D graphics. It uses the HTML5 canvas element and is accessed using Document Object Model interfaces. You can even use shaders...

Another solution to "combine" Blender with you browser content, is to simply export images from Blender and use then with html...

Next, you can use 3D plug-ins such as [UNITY](http://unity3d.com/unity/) but it's already far from your "PHP" question ;)