# What Program Was Used To Make Call Of Duty?

Tags: game-design

i was wondering what program i should download to make my OWN version of COD I already know unity http://unity3d.com/ but no others. Could someone help me?

Comment: Well, well, well. You could download a few hundred people with decades of experience. Doing a big AAA title such as COD isn't an easy task, you should probably [start with an easier one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with).

Comment: Don't forget to download few million dollars.

Comment: GDSE is not interested in trivia questions (see several discussions on meta) on "what was used for what game", or "featureX of gameY". if you want to know how to implement a specific aspect of this game abstract it away from the game if you can, and then ask that. and the answer to many of these type question is "game engine", but if this game is your goal I agree with lorancou

Answer (score 3):

Call of Duty was most likely programmed in C++ and DirectX.

Unity should be enough to "make your own version".