# Game Dev where to go

Tags: game-design, game-maker, game-industry

I crave to become game Dev. I have watched tried and even made my first game tutored by brackeys that is a cube dodge game. I felt very happy and successful.but what to do to develop rather than buying courses costing lot of dollars. I have experience with unity but still could not get myself immersed frequently in spite of my passion for developing games. People could have same problems as mine. Please suggest me something.whatever u feel guys. Also coding ain't much of a problem. I have inspired from a lot of projects tried them and failed n even quit them even before 25 percent. I know the benefits of starting small and keeping simple which I learnt from extra credits channel yt. But u wanna learn stuff that I do not know and that too as I work in small projects for u or other people with the only goal of acquiring knowledge and skill.i use unity for a while like a month with for twthree again get inspired and cycle goes on.i want help and inspiration on making awesome content

Comment: Start _small_. Don't aim _to learn_, aim to _finish a project_. You could check [this closed question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with) for inspiration. Game dev _looks_ glam, but it's actually really hard.

Comment: If you have issues with a game you're developing, this site is a good place to ask. But we're not focused on discussing ideas, and broad discussions; this is why your question is closed.