# What kind of game is best to learn the basics

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, unreal-4

I am interested in learning Unreal Engine. What kind of game should I aim to build as a beginner which will teach me the most? Thanks.

Comment: This question might help you: [What are good games to "earn your wings" with?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with) Although note that the question is engine-agnostic, so it recommends a lot of projects which are probably easier to do without a game engine than with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unreal supports almost every imaginable type of gameplay and they all use most of the same systems, just in slightly different ways.

It comes with example scenes for a number of different types of game (FPS, Top-down, etc)

Pick one and start trying to modify the game world to suit your interests.

Eg in the top-down example scene, the player character can already navigate to
a click.

Try expanding the walkable area and adding some navmesh complexity, or change how widely the player avoids objects, or perhaps you want to create dozens of gems and start tracking/displaying the player score as they're collected.

It doesn't really matter what you do... All of it will be a learning experience, just use google and youtube liberally. It's very unlikely you're the first person trying to do *{whatever you choose}*.

Comment: Great, I will try to start with something basic like ping-pong.

Comment: Great way to start... You'll learn about handling input to move the "bat", then collisions (and possibly the physics engine) to handle the ball hitting things, plus some game logic to handle scoring, game over, etc...

Comment: Great, thanks for the recommendations.